# JSON to PHP Variable Auto Generate?

Tags: php, json, automation

I have a huge JSON return from an API that produces many possible returned items. I've found that programming the PHP variables to decode this JSON and then echo it back into a table on a page has been very time consuming. This got me thinking that there must be some way to load a JSON file and auto generate the PHP strings needed to parse and control each item.

Here's an example...

```
$one = $data['json']['item1']['subitem1'];
$two = $data['json']['item1']['subitem2'];
```

This JSON return I'm working with has about 500 possible items, is there some kind of program or even a small script anyone knows of that can generate these variables for me?

Comment: Do you mean something like [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)? If not, please clarify your problem, because it sounds like you just need help parsing a JSON data file into a structure you can use.

Comment: To be a developer is to spend many hours behind the keyboard. One does not simply find an easy solution to every task. You are right though, it can be very time consuming to do certain tasks. Over time, as you learn and grow as a developer, you'll do things faster and they won't seem so painful. For now, show us what you're using for code, and provide us with a response so we can know what you're dealing with. It's hard to offer real advice with the limited amount of info and code you've provided.